# Working and Importance of namespaces in XML for a XML parser

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

For a JAVA project I have to parse an XML file, the file contains the tags with namespaces.
For ex:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ns1:root xmlns:ns1="URI1" xmlns:ns2="URI2">
 <ns1:header>
  <ns2:tag1>TRADES</ns2:tag1>
 </ns1:header>
 <ns1:books>
  <ns1:book>
   <ns2:name>ABC</ns2:name>
   <ns1:author>Registered</ns1:author>
  </ns1:book>
 </ns1:books>
</ns1:root>
```

According to my understanding the namespaces are a way to reduce the scope for unique names (in simplest way possible).

I have two main questions here:

1) Could you help me understand how any library with the support of namespaces uses a namespace?

For ex: In this tag-> ns2:tag1

Will it visit URI of ns2 and somehow fetch some data to use?

2) I am faced with 2 choices:

- To make use of these namespaces using the java libraries
- To consider it as a plain text and use the full ns2:tag1 to get the data out of XML since it guarantees a unique name anyway.

Which one is a reliable approach out of above ?

Please correct me if any information above is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The uri (in your case "URI1" and "URI2") can be any string. The unmarshaller of JaxB does not attempt to load the uri. The name of it counts, not the document it might refer to.

If you write:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<ns1:root xmlns:ns1="URI1" xmlns:blaba="URI1">
    <ns1:author>Registered</ns1:author>
    <blabla:author>Registered</blabla:author>
</ns1:root>
```

then both authors are of the same type/class.

It is possible to configure JaxB to ignore namespaces, but I would not recommend this unless you have a good reason.